# Errod:Escaping AWK commands in subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to know what all I must escape here to get the subprocess command successful.

I have already tried the other solutions provided at stack overflow.

```
>>> stdin,stdout,stderr = sp.Popen(["ps -ef |grep -i user1 |awk '{print $NF}'"],shell=True,stdout=sp.PIPE).communicate()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: `Popen.communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdout_data, stderr_data)`. So try, `stdout, stderr = sp.Popen(...).communicate()`

Answer (score 1):

Popen returns a tuple of two data streams (`stdout, stderr`), not 3. Pass anything you want to *send* to `communicate` as the `input` parameter.

> `communicate()` returns a tuple (`stdout_data`, `stderr_data`). The data will be strings if streams were opened in text mode; otherwise, bytes.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html